# Inheriting from IO::File

Tags: perl, oop, inheritance

I have this simple base class (Module):

```
package XMSP::File;
use parent 'IO::File';

sub new {
    my ($self,@args) = @_;
    my $object = {};

    bless($object,$self);
    $object->SUPER::new(@args);

    return $object;
}

sub open {
    my ($self,@args) = @_;
    $self->SUPER::open(@args);
}

sub close {
    my ($self,@args) = @_;
    $self->SUPER::close(@args);
}
1;
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use XMSP::File;

my $file = XMSP::File->new("< $0");

if (defined $file) {
    print "First Ok\n";
    $file->close();
}

$file->open("< file");

if (defined $file) {
    print "Second Ok\n";
}
```

On my script I load it using `use` ... I use the ctor (new) to create a new object, etc. but when I close it, it dies with the following error:

```
First Ok
Not a GLOB reference at /usr/lib/perl/5.10/IO/Handle.pm line 115.
```

I can't really figure it out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of letting IO::File create the object, you create it, and you create it completely wrong. You didn't even use the right variable type (hash vs glob). Let IO::File create the object.

```
sub new {
    my ($class, @args) = @_;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new(@args);
    return $self;
}
```

Note that this method is completely redundant. I presume you intend to do additional work in it.

Comment: Yes I do. I just didnt write OO perl for quite some time now (-: Thanks